# Post Redirect Get best practice in case state not saved

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

Its known that PRG pattern should be followed for the POST requests which saves the state.

But when some business validation fails and decided not to save state as part of the POST request, do we need to follow the PRG or just return the view (in case of ASP.NET MVC)

What is the best practice regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If validation fails, simply redisplay the same view. If validation succeeds you modify some state on the server and perform a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

PRG pattern is used to [avoid duplicate form submissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). It would be better to follow this pattern in scenarios which involve a "state" change which impacts the user (deduction from credit card, order submission).

So even in case of business-validation failure on the server, the problem of user refreshing the page still exists, so why not use PRG in this scenario as well?